# VS code ouput empty

Tags: visual-studio-code, output

I recently started to use vscode. In the beginning I used to get the output in the output tab. But recently the output tab is not showing the output but output is showing in the terminal tab. I unchecked the run in terminal option but still the output is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: with what you are showing, how on earth do you think we will be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Usually, the code we run is output in the terminal,

If you want to get output in output, you can download the extension named "code runner".

[image]

If you don't check this option, it will be output in output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, which will cause your content to be displayed in the output window.

In addition, add the following code in `setting.json` to control whether to output in the terminal.

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": false
```

You can also add: `"console": "internalConsole"` in `launch.json`, then click F5 to debug the code, this will output in DEBUG CONSOLE.